# ANSI 92 Date Difference not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff, ansi-sql-92

I'm, trying to calculate the number of days between two dates using ANSI SQL standard. But I'm missing something as this statement returns NULL in MySQL.

`SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM  DATE('2009-01-25')  -  DATE('2009-01-01')) AS day_diff;`

I'm aware of the MySQL DATEDIFF function, but I'm curious why this code isn't working.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you `extract DAY` from a date, you lose the month and year. So this does not look like a valid way to achieve what you want. Perhaps the simple `DATE('2009-01-25') - DATE('2009-01-01')` is ANSI SQL, not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you meant to do?

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2009-01-25')) - 
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2009-01-01')) AS day_diff;
+----------+
| day_diff |
+----------+
|       24 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

UPDATE:

If you want this to work for dates in different months (or even different years), then you can use the MySQL `DATEDIFF()` function.

Examples:

```
mysql> select datediff('2009-04-25','2009-01-01');
+-------------------------------------+
| datediff('2009-04-25','2009-01-01') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                 114 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select datediff('2010-04-25','2009-01-01');
+-------------------------------------+
| datediff('2010-04-25','2009-01-01') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                 479 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This seems to fail when the months are different.


`SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2009-04-25')) - 
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2009-01-01')) AS day_diff;`

Comment: I mentioned it in my initial post, but I'm aware of DATEDIFF. I was wondering why the statement I posted wasn't working as I thought it were the ANSI 92 standard for accomplishing what I'm trying to do.